# Get the specific page of a given element using Spring data JpaRepository

Tags: java, rest, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I need to know the excatly server-side page (page 4 of 10 for example) that contains an element.

If I have the numbers from 0 to 100, and the element which page I'm looking for is the number 54, given a page length of 10, the resulted page should be the 5th one (starting on 0), which contains the elements from 50 to 59.

Does the Spring JpaRepository a way to achieve this? 
Is there even an already implemented way to do it  (with acceptable performance for thousands of elements)?

My situation is that I have a spring rest api application working, and i have some pages with server-side pagination also working. The client side is built using Angular 8.

I'm want to implement the next list-detail view.

[image]

The button "new entity" redirects the user to a new page where he can create a new Entity (obvious). After the entity has been created (using another api endpoing), the Angular app must return to the previous list-detail page.

Here comes the problem. I need to show the page in which the new entity is (ignoring the filters an configurations previously made).

I've done a fast research over the JpaRepository definition and all the methods I've seen work with the class Pageable. I think I cannot achieve what I'm looking for just using that class or that repository

Thank you.

**UPDATE 01**

The real point to achieve here is to get the page where the element is, not just make the element appear in the page shown (like codebrane proposed) ordering by the creation date.

I would want to go directly to that element detail from outside of the list-detail page for other reasons than just being created, like just checking the element detail for info purposes.

Comment: can you order the list by creation date? then the new entity will always be on the first page

Comment: That will solve the problem partially (not seeing the created entity when returning). It's not exactly what I want, I updated the question with more info. Thx anyway.